# Error on resizing image with ng2-img-max in Angular 8

Tags: angular

When I updated to Angular 8, my resizing method with `ng2-img-max` stopped working and now shows this error.

```
core.js:6014 ERROR ReferenceError: n is not defined
    at getStringFromDB (exif.js:741)
    at readEXIFData (exif.js:748)
    at findEXIFinJPEG (exif.js:449)
    at handleBinaryFile (exif.js:370)
    at FileReader.fileReader.onload (exif.js:391)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:39699)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
    at Zone.runGuarded (zone-evergreen.js:134)
    at FileReader.<anonymous> (zone-evergreen.js:118)
```

The code is:

```
this.ng2ImgMax.resize([image], 1000, 200).subscribe
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: I've edited your question to add the information above but, in future, please add additional information directly by editing the question rather than by adding comments below the question.

Comment: help please i`m waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it with using 
npm i ngx-image-compress
and uninstall ng2-img-max
see this link 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-compress